# When should I use keydown and keyup?

Tags: keyevent, user-friendly

Which event should be used for key press handling key-down/key-up? It is sure that in both case the program will run successfully. But which one will be more user-friendly?

Comment: This is a good question, and I haven't yet seen a good answer for it anywhere online. UX StackExchange has a similar question more focused on the "user experience" side of this question: [Which event type is preferable for keyboard interactions, "key up" or "key down"?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/133937/which-event-type-is-preferable-for-keyboard-interactions-key-up-or-key-down/151057#151057)

Answer (score 8):

It depends on you. There is no such best practice. Both are used as per the need of your program and as per the convenience of the user.

**keyup**
Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

**keydown**
Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

Check out this [page describing the differences](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708235602/http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx).